# Making a HTTP request to API possible with VB/ASP classic?

Tags: api, asp-classic, httpwebrequest, request

Is it possible to make requests to a Web API with ASP classic?

For example just something as simple as the Flickr API, or was this sort of thing not supported way back when?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite possible:

```
Dim req
Set req = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

req.open "GET", "http://blabla.com", False
req.send()

Response.Write(req.responseText)
```

You should be able to find examples of how to parse XML and JSON here on stackoverflow.com