# how to read a .txt file from different server in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic

I´m reading a text file from my server as I should with the below, but I wonder how I can read a txt file from a different server? What do I need to do to get it working?

```
Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("files.txt"), 1)

do while f.AtEndOfStream = false
Response.Write(f.ReadLine)
Response.Write("<br>")
loop

f.Close
Set f=Nothing
Set fs=Nothing
```

So this is working as it should, but I want to change the files.txt to http://www.somedomain.com/files.txt

Any input appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you try with some other domain ? If so, what issues you faced ?

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695999/how-to-read-text-file-in-classic-asp)

Comment: @hs.chandra, He is able to read the text file through his code. He is asking how to open a remote file(which is not on his server).

Comment: Shankar, exactly right!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a HTTP request to API possible with VB/ASP classic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883444/making-a-http-request-to-api-possible-with-vb-asp-classic)

Comment: I only get "Bad file name or number" if I try to have the http...

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson — Yes. You want to read a resource over HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claes , try this and let us know.

```
<% Option Explicit %>
<%
Const REMOTE_FILE_URL="http://www.somedomain.com/files.txt"

Call ShowRemoteFile

Sub ShowRemoteFile
    Dim objXML, strContents, arrLines
    Dim x
    Set objXML=Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    'read text file...
    objXML.Open "GET", REMOTE_FILE_URL, False
    objXML.Send
    strContents=objXML.ResponseText
    Set objXML=Nothing

    'split into lines and read line by line...
    arrLines=Split(strContents, VBCrLf)
    For x=0 To UBound(arrLines)
        Response.Write(arrLines(x)&"<br />")
    Next
End Sub
%>
```

Comment: Shankar this works perfect. Reads all the lines and writes them out line by line. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to fetch the text data (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1887522)):

```
Function GetTextFromUrl(url)

  Dim oXMLHTTP
  Dim strStatusTest

  Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

  oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
  oXMLHTTP.Send

  If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then

    GetTextFromUrl = oXMLHTTP.responseText

  End If

End Function

Dim sResult : sResult = GetTextFromUrl("http://www.somedomain.com/files.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks, haim770, yes this is simular to what I got working now.